# Access VBA - Absolute maximum of two pevious max/min fields loop

Tags: vba, ms-access

I keep receiving an error *"Invalid use of Null"* from my Access VBA code. The objective of this VBA code is to loop through a series of tables that contain max, min, mean values repeated and replace the mean field with the absolute maximum value of the previous max and min fields.

```
Left Mx max   Left Mx min   Left Mx mean    Right Mx max    Right Mx min    Right Mx mean
50.754       -33.002        50.75           50.642          -33.0           50.642
-95.355      -167.889       167.88          -95.822         -168.373        168.373
63.636       -45.956        63.636          63.473          -45.984         63.473
-97.065      -165.954       165.954         -97.442         -166.365        166.365
```

The current code I have is able to go through a single table, but once it reaches the end I receive the error.

**Current Code**

```
Sub absolute()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

Dim maximum As Double
Dim minimum As Double
Dim newvalue As Double
Dim newfield As String
Dim newcase As String
Dim sqlStatement As String

Set db = CurrentDb


For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "Case" Or tdf.Name Summmary" 
Or tdf.Name Like "~*") Then

Set rs1 = tdf.OpenRecordset()

    rs1.MoveFirst
    While Not rs1.EOF Or Not Null
        For Each fld In rs1.Fields
        newfield = fld.Name
            If newfield <> "case" Then
                If Right(newfield, 3) = "max" Then
                        maximum = rs1(newfield).Value
                ElseIf Right(newfield, 3) = "min" Then
                    minimum = rs1(newfield).Value
                ElseIf Right(newfield, 4) = "mean" Then
                rs1.Edit
                rs1(newfield).Value = iMax(maximum, minimum)
                rs1.Update
                End If
            End If
        Next fld
    rs1.MoveNext
    Wend
End If
Next tdf


Set fld = Nothing
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing

End Sub
```

Where imax is:

```
Public Function iMax(ParamArray p()) As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim v As Variant

v = p(LBound(p))
For i = LBound(p) + 1 To UBound(p)
  If Abs(v) < Abs(p(i)) Then
     v = p(i)
  End If
Next
iMax = Abs(v)
End Function
```

In addition how can I change the field names from "mean" to "abs" within the current code?

**Edit**

The code is halted at:

```
maximum = rs1(newfield).Value
'where rs1(newfield which is storing left mx max) = null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following part this should eliminate your Null error.

```
Set rs1 = tdf.OpenRecordset()
rs1.MoveFirst
While Not rs1.EOF Or Not Null
    'For Each fld In rs1.Fields    -- old
     For Each fld In tdf.Fields   '-- new 
    newfield = fld.Name
        If newfield <> "case" Then
            If Right(newfield, 3) = "max" Then
                    maximum = rs1(newfield).Value
            ElseIf Right(newfield, 3) = "min" Then
                minimum = rs1(newfield).Value
            ElseIf Right(newfield, 4) = "mean" Then
            rs1.Edit
            rs1(newfield).Value = iMax(maximum, minimum)
            rs1.Update
            End If
        End If
    Next fld
    rs1.MoveNext
Wend
End If
Next tdf
```

But i would recommend to seperate the procedures (single responsibility). e.g. a separate function for evaluating the fieldnames.

I don' t know exactly what you mean with changing field names. Do you want to change the fieldnames of the table by code?

For changing the fieldname i just wrote the necessary parts of the client to demonstrate the calling of the sub

```
Public Sub ClientCall()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim searchName As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("Tabelle1")
searchName = "Max"
ChangeFieldName tdf, searchName, Len(searchName), "Abs"
```

End Sub

The Sub ChangeFieldname does not have any error handling e.g. Table is readonly and things like that

```
Public Sub ChangeFieldName(ByRef Table As DAO.TableDef, ByVal ExistingAbbreviation As String, ByVal CompareLastCharactersOfField As Integer, ByVal NewAbbrevation As String)
' assuming that existingAbbreviation has exactly the same number of characters as the CompareLastCharactersOfField
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim currentFieldName As String

For Each fld In Table.Fields
    currentFieldName = fld.Name
    FieldSuffix = Right(currentFieldName, CompareLastCharactersOfField)
    If FieldSuffix = ExistingAbbreviation Then
        'take the part of the fieldname which should stay
        fieldPrefix = Left(currentFieldName, Len(currentFieldName) - CompareLastCharactersOfField)
        newFieldName = fieldPrefix + NewAbbrevation
        fld.Name = newFieldName
    End If
Next fld
End Sub
```

Regarding the null exception in the recordset this should help. The value 0 is an example. I don' t know how you want to treat Null Values so please take it as an example. The problem is that double values must not contain null values!

```
If IsNull(rs1(newField).Value) Then
        maximum = 0
    Else
        maximum = rs1(newField).Value
    End If
```

Comment: You are correct, I want to change "Left Mx mean" to "Left Mx abs" in the table by code.

Comment: I replaced the line that you suggested but I am still receiving the same null message error.